# What is the best way to share a USB drive on Win7

Tags: windows-7, usb, network-shares

I'm having trouble sharing my USB drives on Win7. I share them and set permissions to everyone (like the primary C and D drives that are shared sucessfully). But the USB drive doesn't come up.

[Other](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-networking-sharing/220453-sharing-external-usb-hard-drive.html) [people](http://www.aboutfortunate.com/Technology-Blog.aspx?entid=14) [seem](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/230515-automatically-sharing-usb-external-hd-flash-drive-when-plugged.html) to [have](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/add-device-computer-to-network#1TC=windows-7) had this issue with mixed results:

I saw [a forum post](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6122_102-246730/how-to-share-a-usb-external-hard-drive-on-a-home-network/) that suggested changing the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters` for the value `IRPStackSize`. I'm nervous about touching the registry.

My question is: **What is the best way to share a USB drive on Win7?**

Comment: Are you sharing the root of the drive? (Thats a bad idea, securitywise)

Comment: Yeah - that was the plan - does it make a difference?

Comment: I distinctly recall windows file sharing gets kind of grouchy when you do that. You're MUCH better off sharing specific folders. I just have a main share folder on my networked drives and chuck everything there.

Comment: Cool - can you expand that into an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows tends to get grouchy when you share the root of a drive - its a bad idea security wise. You're much better off sharing specific folders. Practically there's not much difference between sharing X: and X:\sharing anyway from the end user perspective.